Unable to connect to Postgres (using Go and Docker)
I am attempting to make a Docker container containing a Go module and a Postgres database respectively.
However my Go module is unable to connect to my Postgres database.
What I've tried is the following:
.env
HOST=0.0.0.0
SERVER_PORT=3000
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=12345
DB_NAME=unity
DB_PORT=5432

docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  scraper:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: go run cmd/main.go
  air:
    image: cosmtrek/air:latest
    # working_dir value has to be the same of mapped volume
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment:
      - ENV_A=${ENV_A}
      - ENV_B=${ENV_B}
      - ENV_C=${ENV_C}
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d ${DB_NAME} -U ${DB_USER}"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  postgres_db:

database.go
package databases

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/DespairServices/despair-services-scrapper/internal/models"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

var db *gorm.DB
var dsn string = fmt.Sprintf(
    "host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai",
    os.Getenv("HOST"),
    os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PORT"),
)

func Connect() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to database. \n", err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    log.Println("Database Connected!")

    log.Println("Running Migrations...")
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Asset{})
    log.Println("Migrations Done!")
}

When launching Postgres it confirms to me the IP being used:
2024-04-05 21:03:27 2024-04-06 01:03:27.074 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-04-05 21:03:27 2024-04-06 01:03:27.074 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-04-05 21:03:27 2024-04-06 01:03:27.083 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-04-05 21:03:27 2024-04-06 01:03:27.093 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-06 01:00:11 UTC
2024-04-05 21:03:27 2024-04-06 01:03:27.103 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

However my Go Module is unable to connect to that very address...
2024-04-05 21:04:48 2024/04/06 01:04:48 /usr/src/app/internal/databases/database.go:26
2024-04-05 21:04:48 [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=0.0.0.0 user=postgres database=unity`: dial error (dial tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: connect: connection refused)

I'm just confused at this point, any help is appreciated.

Try connecting to 127.0.0.1 (or localhost). Postgres is a 'listening' service so it can legitimatly bind to 0.0.0.0 (or INADDR_ANY) - the client (your Go application) needs to connect to specific IP address - which would normally be 127.0.0.1 for this scenario.

@tonys I tired changing it to the 2 values to suggest but I still get [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres database=unity: dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused)and [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to host=localhost user=postgres database=unity: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)

TLDR Use the Docker network name for the database service (postgres) rather than 0.0.0.0. Change the first line in .env:
HOST=postgres
SERVER_PORT=3000
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=12345
DB_NAME=unity
DB_PORT=5432

Details
Minimal setup to get this working, having stripped off non-essential services etc.
 docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  scraper:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file:
      - .env
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d ${DB_NAME} -U ${DB_USER}"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  postgres_db:


 Dockerfile
FROM golang:alpine3.19

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go mod tidy
RUN go build -o main .

CMD ./main

 main.go (Based on your database.go but without migrations.)
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

var db *gorm.DB
var dsn string = fmt.Sprintf(
    "host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai",
    os.Getenv("HOST"),
    os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PORT"),
)

func main() {   
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to database. \n", err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    log.Println("Database Connected!")
}


I realized I should of supplied my post with the Dockerfile, but I forgot... Your solution works though, thanks for the help!
